# Update преобразовать отрицательное число в положительное

Tags: sql

у меня есть таблица в нем положительные и отрицательные числа можно ли сделать отрицательные числа положительными используя update в mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

сделал таким образам все получилось)

```
UPDATE balance SET amount = ABS(amount)
```

Comment: Добавьте условие “where amount < 0”, чтобы не изменять неотрицательные числа

Comment: @MaxU сравнение, наверное, более затратная операция, чем abs()

Comment: @Эникейщик, в БД самые затратные операции - это всегда операции чтения и записи (т.е. работа с диском). В данном случае в решении автора надо прочитать все записи и записать все записи. В моём варианте записывать нужно только изменённые записи и если есть индекс по полю “amount” то и чтение будет быстрее

Comment: @Эникейщик Дополню MaxU - при наличии индекса range scan вообще не станет читать записи с неотрицательными значениями.

Comment: @MaxU ясно, буду знать.